# on touch of YouTube iFrame embed adds delay to clicks on iOS Safari

Tags: ios, youtube, mobile-safari

I've an embedded YouTube video on a page as normal:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dC0kYlHWrZ8" />
```

As you can see if you click the button it increments the count and feels normal and responsive. Now if you touch the video and scroll the page without playing it, it seems to add a delay to the button and it now feels sluggish/requires a hard press.

Once you play/pause the video using the native HTML 5 controls, the button becomes responsive again.

https://jsfiddle.net/qfxma8bj/2/embedded/result

[image]

I cannot seem to stop this behaviour! As our website is an SPA it delays all interactions with the site thereafter and really ruins the experience.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: @ahomphophone no I haven't!

Comment: I have a similar issue. I just discovered that it might be related to this webkit bug:https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=185001. Adding `ontouchstart=""` to the button solves the issue for me.

Comment: @ahomphophone Thanks for some more clues. I will have a look at this and see if I can make any more progress.